# How can I add or remove character from a specified line number in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a file which I must iterate through several times, running it with python each time. How can I remove or add characters from specific lines in shell?

for an example file ex.file,

```
$ cat ex.file
stuff
more stuff
more stuff
more stuff
#<- remove this character
<-add a pund sign here
more stuff
more stuff
```

my desired output would be:

```
$ cat ex.file
stuff
more stuff
more stuff
more stuff
<- remove this character
#<-add a pund sign here
more stuff
more stuff
```

Answer (score 6):

To add a # at the start of line 6:

```
sed '6 s/^/#/' ex.file
```

To remove the leading # from line 5:

```
sed '5 s/^#//' ex.file
```

Comment: How do I direct sed to `ex.file`?

Comment: @kilojoules: See my edit.  You can use `sed -i` instead of just `sed` to edit the file in place, or you can write it to a new file like `sed ... > newfile`.

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I overwrite `ex.file`?

Comment: @kilojoules: I just told you.

Comment: @kilojoules you can do it all in one call `sed -i -e '5 s/^#//' -e '6 s/^/#/' ex.file` and add `-i.bak` to create a backup on the original in `ex.file.bak`.

Answer (score 2):

Oneliner awk version to remove # from 5th line and add # to 6th line.

```
awk 'NR==5 {sub(/^#/,"") } NR==6 { sub(/^/,"#")}1' infile
```